# Passing a function as a parameter onto a list of objects

Tags: java, function, lambda

So I am trying to make a basic game engine, based around the idea of tags, where every object has a bunch of tags that I can use to group things like wall segments and perform actions on them all at once. Since I don't want to have to surround every function with a loop to call it on each object, I am trying to make a method that can call the passed method on each object.

here is some example suto-code:

```
//have a list of objs. some door, some not.

//an example of stuff I could want to do
//  - check returns on any functions called
//  - call a function on a bunch of objects, possibly with parameters
if (runOnTag("door", isClosed())[aPositionInReturnList] == true){
    runOnTag("door", open());
}

//the method
public couldBeAnyType[] runOnTag(String tag, function(anyPerams)){    //dont want the function to compile here
    for (String currentObj : listOfObjsWith[tag]){
        returns[index++] = currentObj.function(anyPerams);     //so that it can be executed on this object
    }
    return returns;    //want to be able to colect returns
}
```

I have already looked through a bunch of other answers to this type of question, but I don't understand what is going on in them. If anyone could explain it more simply, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: can you show the definition of your list of objects? there should be better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: you do not have objects that change tags dynamically.

Why not implement your tags as interfaces? This is faster than string matching, type-safe and in general more efficient.

```
interface Door {boolean isClosed(); void open();}

class State {
   private Collection<Object> gameObjects;

   public <T,R> Stream<R> onTagged(Class<T> type, Function<T,R> apply) {
      return gameObjects
           .stream()
           .filter(type::isInstance)
           .map(type::cast)
           .map(apply);
   }
}
```

Ignore the name (`onTagged`), make your own. This can be used like this f.e. to find if there is any door open:

```
State state = ...;
if(state.onTagged(Door.class, door -> !door.isClosed()).anyMatch(Boolean.TRUE::equals)) {
  // ... do stuff ...
}
```

You will however find that it's usually better like this, because then you can compose operations (map/filter/any*) very easily:

```
   public <T> Stream<T> withTag(Class<T> type) {
      return gameObjects
           .stream()
           .filter(type::isInstance)
           .map(type::cast);
   }

if(state.withTag(Door.class).anyMatch(door -> !door.isClosed())) {
  // ... do stuff ...
}
```